# Why my Tabbar's userinteraction is Enabled when come from popviewcontroller to another view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, user-interaction

Please review my code where i am wrong.

first time when my app is launch every thing is fine

> tabBars.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled=NO;

This code is working fine means my tabbar userInteraction is OFF. But i will go to another view and simple use the `popViewController` and come to first view my userInteraction is Enabled why?
I am not able to found this problem.

```
EATabBarVC *tabBars = [[EATabBarVC alloc] init];
UIImage *tabBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BottomTabBar.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:tabBarImage];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, tabBars.tabBar.frame.size.height);
[imageView sizeToFit];
tabBars.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
[tabBars.tabBar insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
tabBars.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:136/255.f green:159/255.f blue:186/255.f alpha:1];
tabBars.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
tabBars.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    NSMutableArray *localViewControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

    EAHomeVC *objEAHomeVC = [[EAHomeVC alloc] init];




    UINavigationController *dashboardNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objEAHomeVC];

    dashboardNavController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;


    EAScanLeadsVC *objEAScanLeadsVC = [[EAScanLeadsVC alloc] init];
    objEAScanLeadsVC.delegate = self;
    objEAScanLeadsVC.tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0.0, -3.0);
    if (IS_IPHONE6PLUS) {
        objEAScanLeadsVC.tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0.0, -6.0);
    }
    if (IS_IPADAIR2||IS_IPADMINI) {
        objEAScanLeadsVC.tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0.0, -12.0);

    }

    [objEAScanLeadsVC.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:136/255.f green:159/255.f blue:186/255.f alpha:1],NSFontAttributeName : ROBOTOLIGHT(5.39*2.2)}
                                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [objEAScanLeadsVC.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],NSFontAttributeName : ROBOTOLIGHT(5.39*2.2) }
                                          forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    UINavigationController *scanNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objEAScanLeadsVC];
    //scanNavController.title = @"Scan Lead";
    scanNavController.tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0.0, -3.0);
    if (IS_IPHONE6PLUS) {
        scanNavController.tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0.0, -6.0);

    }
    if (IS_IPADAIR2||IS_IPADMINI) {
        scanNavController.tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0.0, -12.0);

    }

    [scanNavController.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:136/255.f green:159/255.f blue:186/255.f alpha:1],NSFontAttributeName : ROBOTOLIGHT(5.39*2.2) }
                                                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [scanNavController.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],NSFontAttributeName : ROBOTOLIGHT(5.39*2.2) }
                                                forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [tabBars addCenterButtonWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBarScan.png"] highlightImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBarScan.png"]];






    [localViewControllersArray addObject:dashboardNavController];
    [localViewControllersArray addObject:scanNavController];


    tabBars.viewControllers = localViewControllersArray;
    tabBars.view.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    tabBars.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    [tabBars.tabBar setItemWidth:self.view.frame.size.width/3];
    [tabBars.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:136/255.f green:159/255.f blue:186/255.f alpha:1],NSFontAttributeName : ROBOTOLIGHT(5.39*2.2) }
                                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tabBars.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],NSFontAttributeName : ROBOTOLIGHT(5.39*2.2) }
                                               forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    return [[EABaseCenterVC alloc]
            initWithRootViewController:tabBars];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code its may be helpful.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[[[[self.tabBarController tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:0]setEnabled:FALSE];
[[[[self.tabBarController tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:1]setEnabled:FALSE];
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[[[[self.tabBarController tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:0]setEnabled:FALSE];
[[[[self.tabBarController tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:1]setEnabled:FALSE];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS and other 3rd party components have some in-built behaviours that may enable it on viewWillAppear or something similar. Try putting your line

```
tabBars.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
```

in the

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

or

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

of the views you want to disable the interaction for

Comment: any another way to disabled the tabbar

Answer (score 0):

Is your above code in viewDidLoad(), If yes then remove it from there and add it into viewWillAppear().

Try it may work for you.